# need to find python regex to get only the last digit

Tags: python, regex

I have a huge pdf that is all very basic text on pages for invoices, I need to create a regex or 2 so when I split it I get the customer number and the invoice number to use in the file name. I am using python 3 and pypdf2 currently

text example of 2 of the pages:

```
Detailed Invoice Report
Starting 8/12/2015 and ending 8/11/2022
Company:  (Multiple Companies) Printed by Robert S on 8/11/2022   1:26:46PM
Donna Contact Cust# Name: Customer A  1234
Customer A Invoice Date Invoice Name 8/12/2015  241849
Item Description Qty Price Extended Price
Credit ($810.00)  1 ($810.00) 1
Due Paid Total Total Taxes Subtotal
($810.00) ($810.00) $0.00 ($810.00)
Balance: ($810.00) $0.00 $0.00 
8/11/2022   1:26:46PM Page 1 of 340977

Detailed Invoice Report
Starting 8/12/2015 and ending 8/11/2022
Company:  (Multiple Companies) Printed by Robert S on 8/11/2022   1:26:46PM
Customer B Cust# Name: Customer B  45678
Customer B Invoice Date Invoice Name 8/12/2015  241850
Item Description Qty Price Extended Price
credit ($49.99)  1 ($49.99) 1
Due Paid Total Total Taxes Subtotal
($49.99) ($49.99) $0.00 ($49.99)
Balance: ($49.99) $0.00 $0.00 
8/11/2022   1:26:46PM Page 2 of 340977
```

currently I have these 2 regex filters to get each one kind of but I do not know how to only keep the last groups match from them.
Note: the firstmatch regex is broken if the customer name has a number in it which is an edge case but not uncommon in the data

```
firstmatch=r"(Name:)(\D*)(\d+)"
secondmatch=r"(Name )(\d*.\d*.\d*..)(\d*)"
```

Each one is its own page and I would like the regex to be able to pull from the first one 1234 241849 and the second one 45678 241850

Comment: `re.search(firstmatch, foo).group(3)`, etc.? Where `foo` is your string to search. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group), `m.group(2)       # The second parenthesized subgroup.`, etc..

Comment: @Axe319 that should always work for the secondmatch one but how about the edge case for the first one that has numbers in the string before the number at the end currently group2's portion would miss it

Comment: `(?:...)` can be used to make a non-capturing group. So `(Name )(\d*.\d*.\d*..)(\d*)` can be changed to `(Name )(?:\d*.\d*.\d*..)(\d*)` so that group 2 still refers to the ID you're interested in.

Comment: Can you always expect a space? If so, why not `re.search(r'(Name:)(.*) (\d+$)', foo).group(3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get both values using a capture matching the last digits on the line.

For the first pattern:

```
\bName:.*?\b(\d+)[^\d\n]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `\bName:` Match `Name:` preceded by a word boundary
- `.*?` Match any character without a newline, as least as possible
- `\b(\d+)` A word boundary, then capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `[^\d\n]*` Optionally match any character except digits or a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wdqlkW/1)

For the second pattern you can make it a bit more specific, where `[^\S\n]+` matches 1+ whitespace chars without newlines:

```
\bName[^\S\n]+\d+/\d+/\d+[^\S\n]+(\d+)[^\d\n]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3q3A9N/1)

Or if the lines are right behind each other, you can also use 1 pattern with 2 capture groups and match the newline at the end of the first line:

```
\bName:.*?\b(\d+)[^\d\n]*\n\b.*?Name[^\S\n]+\d+/\d+/\d+[^\S\n]+(\d+)[^\d\n]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0X7UCv/1)

Comment: In my case I used the last one and it worked flawlessly. Thank you